# SUM of "Amount" column in DATAGRID's DataGridTemplateColumn RUNTIME

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

We have WPF application, In which we use DataGrid on one form.
At runtime, when we Enter value in DataTemplate column, I need to Show SUM of that specific column in DATAGRID Footer.
So when each time I change value in any Cell of That AMOUNT column, The correct SUM of that column need to be display.
Which event I should try. 
I have tried this code , But it need to press tab each time, it does not display Correct SUM.

```
 private void dgInfo_RowEditEnding(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
 {
      Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow row = this.dgInfo.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(e.Row.GetIndex()) as Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow;
      ContentPresenter CP = dgInfo.Columns[3].GetCellContent(row) as ContentPresenter;

      TextBlock t = FindVisualChild<TextBlock>(CP);
      if (t != null && t.Text.Length > 0)
      {
         decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(t.Text);
         sum = sum + d;
         txtTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
      }
 }
```

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: You want it to update as you're typing and not only when you leave the field?

Comment: No , when I leave that field. It will be ok. please provide code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 void dgInfo_CellEditEnding(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
                       decimal tot = 0;
                       GetFaltyExpenseGridResult newRecord;
                       for (int i = 0; i < (dgInfo.Items.Count - 1); i++)
                       {
                           newRecord = (GetFaltyExpenseGridResult)((ContentPresenter)dgInfo.Columns[0].GetCellContent(dgInfo.Items[i])).Content;

                           if (newRecord != null)
                           {

                                   decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(newRecord.Amount);
                                   tot = tot + d;
                                   txtTotal.Text = tot.ToString();

                           }
                       }
       }
```